# Need help to find average, min and max values in shell script from text file

Tags: bash, shell

I'm working on a shell script right now. I need to loop through a text file, grab the text from it, and find the average number, max number and min number from each line of numbers then print them in a chart with the name of each line. This is the text file:

```
Experiment1 9 8 1 2 9 0 2 3 4 5
collect1 83 39 84 2 1 3 0 9
jump1 82 -1 9 26 8 9
exp2 22 0 7 1 0 7 3 2
jump2 88 7 6 5
taker1 5 5 44 2 3
```

so far all I can do is loop through it and print each line like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
echo $line
done < mystats.txt
```

I'm a beginner and nothing I've found online has helped me.

Answer (score 4):

One way, using `perl` for all the calculations:

```
$ perl -MList::Util=min,max,sum -anE 'BEGIN { say "Name\tAvg\tMin\tMax" }
    $n = shift @F; say join("\t", $n, sum(@F)/@F, min(@F), max(@F))' mystats.txt
Name    Avg     Min     Max
Experiment1     4.3     0       9
collect1        27.625  0       84
jump1   22.1666666666667        -1      82
exp2    5.25    0       22
jump2   26.5    5       88
taker1  11.8    2       44
```

It uses autosplit mode (`-a`) to split each line into an array (Much like `awk`), and the standard `List::Util` module's math functions to calculate the mean, min, and max of each line's numbers.

---

And here's a pure `bash` version using nothing but builtins (Though I don't recommend doing this; among other things `bash` doesn't do floating point math, so the averages are off):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf "Name\tAvg\tMin\tMax\n"
while read name nums; do
    read -a numarr <<< "$nums"
    total=0
    min=${numarr[0]}
    max=${numarr[0]}
    for n in "${numarr[@]}"; do
        (( total += n ))
        if [[ $n -lt $min ]]; then
            min=$n
        fi
        if [[ $n -gt $max ]]; then
            max=$n
        fi
    done
    (( avg = total / ${#numarr[*]} ))
    printf "%s\t%d\t%d\t%d\n" "$name" "$avg" "$min" "$max"
done < mystats.txt
```

Comment: `(( avg = (total * 100 + 5) / ${#numarr[*]} )); let len=${#avg}-2; avg=${avg:0:-2}.${avg:$len}`

Answer (score 3):

Using [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK):

```
awk '{
  min = $2; max = $2; sum = $2;
  for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
    if (min > $i) min = $i;
    if (max < $i) max = $i;
    sum+=$i }
  printf "for %-20s min=%10i max=%10i avg=%10.3f\n", $1, min, max, sum/(NF-1) }' mystats.txt
```